# ¿cómo puedo combinar una fila completa de un DataGridView en C# Forms?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, datagridview

Actualmente tengo un DataGridView que está de la siguiente forma por poner un ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera combinar la ultima fila, de tal forma que quedara de esta forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo que estoy usando para la ultima fila es el siguiente

```
 myDGV.Rows.Add("", "", "Son: " + MontoTXT.Text.ToUpper(), "", "");
```

Estuve buscando algo que me podría funcionar y encontré este fragmento de código

```
 private void Grilla_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        
            if (e.ColumnIndex >= 0 && e.RowIndex == Grilla.Rows.Count - 1)
            {
                e.AdvancedBorderStyle.Left = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;
            }
        
    }
```

El problema es que solo elimina el borde pero el tamaño de la "celda" es igual.

Quisiera que se pueda combinar la ultima fila unicamente, ya que con el contenido podria ser mucho mas largo que el espacio en esa unica celda

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16775269/8166997 esa respuesta puede serte útil

Comment: acabo de ver, una de las formas sería con Drawer al parecer, o solo "quizas" funcione

Comment: El DataGridView no es un excel porque quieres forzar un componente hacer algo para lo cual no esta pensado. Si quieres mostrar el texto podrias ponerlo por fuera del grid, no se en un Label justo debaja de este

Comment: Tienes razón, ya le busqué una y varias posibles formas de solucionar pero es como dices, no está pensado para eso, la razón para ponerlo dentro del DataGridView era porque estoy usando DGVPrinter y queria que salga eso cerca de la grilla o dentro de la misma, en todo caso, muchisimas gracias a todos de la comunidad.

Comment: No se que sera eso de DGVPrint, pero si es para imprimir datos deberias crear un reporte, no se quizas un .rdlc de reporting service en modo local y pasarle el dataset con la infor que quieres imprimir, asi controlas que datos enviar a la impresora